# When do Google Analytics views take effect and are they retroactive?

Tags: google-analytics

How long does it take to get data reflected in a new view created in analytics?

Whenever a new view is created, is the data being reflected from the time when the analytics account was created or from the point of time when the view was created?

Answer (score 1):

The GA view is not retroactive. Refer this [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553?hl=en). Any new view that is created is associated to the property and any new session data is sent to all the views associated to that property.

So older data has never been sent to the new view, thus they cannot be retroactive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Normally it is from the time you sign up for analytics and place your UA code into the website code.

On the other hand, if you listed your business with Google Business Listings/Maps I have seen partial results show up retroactively but not complete details.